# automate ssh commands using python. Obs. double login required

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

So, my university has a cluster that I want to use. However, to access it, I need to login in a ssh server of the university first, and through it login in the cluster using the ssh again. So, my code looks like this:

```
    def login():
        import paramiko
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh.connect('cupido.iqm.unicamp.br', port=22, username='gabriel', password='*********')
```

Where, cupido.iqm.unicamp.br is the host that I need to access first in order to login the cluster through ssh.

This works, fine. So I tried to login in the cluster with the following function:

```
    def kahuna():
        login()
        ssh.connect('kahuna.iqm.unicamp.br', username='gabrielcesar', password='*********')
        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('ls')
        output=stdout.readlines()
        print '\n'.join(output)
```

Here where it gets all fusy. For me it would make sense to login first using the previous function and then use ssh.connect again the same way I did before. However I get the following error(in the comments)

In summary, is there any way to perform a double login in ssh through python?

Comment: File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\util.py", line 279, in retry_on_signal
    return function()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 338, in <lambda>
    retry_on_signal(lambda: sock.connect(addr))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 10060] A attempt to connect failed because the connected component did not answer properly after a period of time or the established connection failed because the connected host did not answer

Comment: Would recommend removing passwords from anything you post publicly.